# python *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

I have seen the previous stack overflow posts on this topic, but I am still unable to create use these two commands when I try to run my function. I have coded a demo example of a simple moving average that I would like to run through the args,kwargs command.

```
import numpy as np
def moving_average(data,lookback=7,SMA=True): #MA function
    if SMA==True:
        weights=np.repeat(1.0,lookback)/lookback
        smas=np.convolve(data,weights,'valid')
        return smas
```

Just running this function works as expected.

```
data=np.random.randn(100) #randomly 
moving_average(data,lookback=7,SMA=True) #this outputs the correct set of numbers
```

However the second I try to add args and kwargs it breaks down.

```
def test1(*args,**kwargs):
    return moving_average(data,lookback,SMA)
test1(data,lookback=7,SMA=True) #this returns an error, saying my global lookback is not defined
```

What exactly in the *args **kwargs logic am I getting wrong? Ive tried inputting both a tuple and a dictionary but neither of those seem to work.

Comment: That's... not what args and kwargs is for. If you know the argument names, and you just want to pass them on, why do you want to use args/kwargs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `*args` and `**kwargs` to your function not the argument(s) and named argument(s):

```
def test1(*args,**kwargs):
    return moving_average(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example using *args and **kwargs:

```
def test1(*args,**kwargs):
    return moving_average(data,lookback,SMA)
```

`data`, `lookback` and `SMA` are no longer defined. It could be:

```
def test1(*args, **kwargs):
    return moving_average(args[0], kwargs['lookback'], kwargs['SMA'])
```

or

```
def test1(*args, **kwargs):
    return moving_average(*args, **kwargs)
```

The Python tutorial has a section that might help: [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Answer (score 2):

```
def test1(*args,**kwargs):
```

Your function now has two local variables, `args` and `kwargs`. One holds the positional arguments that were passed in (as a tuple), the other the keyword arguments (as a dictionary).

```
return moving_average(data,lookback,SMA)
```

Here you use three variable names (data, lookback and SMA) that don't exist in your function, so you get an error.

You could have done

```
return moving_average(args[0], kwargs['lookback'], kwargs['SMA'])
```

But then your test1 function will only work with an exact call like `test1(data,lookback=7,SMA=True)`. A call like `test1(data, 7, True)` won't work, as then the parameters are all in `args`, none in `kwargs`).

Your function could also pass on the parameters exactly as it received them:

```
return moving_average(*args, **kwargs)
```

That works, but there's no benefit to the `test1` function, it just calls `moving_average` and returns its results, why not call `moving_average` directly.

Answer (score -2):

You can understand args and kwargs in python at PyMentor. Hope it helps you understand.

[how to understand args and kwargs in python](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-understand-args-and-kwargs-in-python)